# Saving layers after QGIS processing

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, save, invalid-data

**Context:** I am trying to clean some bathymetric data (originally as lines) and am facing many challenges within QGIS. I ran into what I believe was a bug with the attribute table in QGIS in 3.24.1 so I updated to 3.36.0 and face new issues with the layers (especially when trying to save them).

**Cleaning Process - High Level**

1. Identify and fix any dangles within the dataset
2. 'Lines to Polygon' the data
3. Dissolve (by contour value)

Then since these polygons all overlap, I execute the difference of each contour (this is where I run into issues).

**Issue Examples:**

- I am getting errors trying to load layers into 3.36 which were perfectly functional in 3.24.'Invalid Data Source ... is not a valid or recognized data source'
  [image]
- The big problem is if I try to do any further geoprocessing on some layers I get a 'Repair data source' message after trying to save it. However, this error doesn't show for every layer, sometimes the processing is fine and others I get stuck here.  [image]

I was able to extract and load all the contour layers individually, but as soon as I do any further processing on select layers (merge and difference tool) then try to save, the data becomes invalid. Within QGIS everything renders and visually processes as expected. Additionally as mentioned, this isn't applicable to every layer, following the exact same process, some layers I am able to process and save where others I can not.

[image]

I have tried everything in my arsenal to solve these issues without any luck. Fixing geometries doesn't work, when I check validity I have no errors in the output, I have took different processing approaches (defining geometry types, dissolving/not dissolving), and everything ultimately ends in the same result. If I try to save the file as a GeoPackage or Shapefile it saves without issue, the problem just occurs when I try to save it as a Geojson.

Based on what I am experiencing, it looks like my dataset has a few 'problem' contours.

Is the issue with my data?

Can I identify and fix it?

Is this a QGIS issue?